# Problem before Login Screen - Fedora 21

Tags: fedora, boot

Have the following problem:

Computer boots till the fedora logo before login.
when I press <kbd>F2</kbd>, I see the following:

(1 of 3) A start job is running for Gnome Display Manager

(2 of 3) A start job is running for Login Service

(3 of 3) A start job is running for Wait for Plymouth Boot Screen

The login screen is not showing up. Before reboot the computer crashed because I did run a recovery software (r-linux) but that broke the system.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try booting your system into single user mode. Google that it is not very hard. If it doesn't work for your current kernel, keep trying with any other kernels listed.

If your server has a software problem and it cannot be booted into single user mode on any kernel, the server is really hosed and you may need to reinstall.

If you can get in with single user mode, there is a good chance your server can be salvaged. You will need to start checking logs and try to find out what broke it.

Comment: Note that in single user mode, many of the servers services are not running.. it is not a functional mode but more for disaster recovery.

Comment: Its not a server, its a normal client at home.

Comment: I came into single user mode, and than? what should i do there? was logged in as root.

Comment: @vfbf4n1893 You should be more clear about you are trying to do in your question, I guess you want to salvage data, so do that and then reinstall everything.

Answer (score 0):

Since you were running a recovery software when the machine crashed. You might have corrupted your system files.

Enter in a tty <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. If you can not, power on your computer, and when it gives you a list of boot options, press <kbd>e</kbd>. Now use the arrow keys and find the bit that says `rgba quiet` and change it `text 3` then press <kbd>F10</kbd>. Now it will boot into text mode. If it also does not work, try with a live usb.

Try to access your `/var/log` folder and check your log files, like `boot.log` and run as root `journalctl -e /usr/libexec/Xorg.bin`

Those log files might give a help in what is happening. Also, you should consider install your Fedora again. In any case, you should back up your data as soon as possible.

Comment: i was logged in as root. was could not use these commands journalctl -e ...

Comment: Can you give more details about the boot.log error messages? It might be a problem with your X server.

Comment: Yes sure:errors at booting are:
failed to start 
/etc/rc.d/rc.local Compatibility /

netowrk Mananger /

Login Service /

Gnome Display Manager /

Apply Kernel Variables